# Compile error with Boost posix date and time in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

I'm attempting to initialize an instance of a Boost ptime object with a std::stringstream object. I'm getting compile errors from the boost/date_time/format_date_parser.hpp stating there is an error converting from int to unsigned short.  Below is a copy of the function causing the error and the headers I've included in the source file.  The purpose of the function is to determine if a file I want to send to another process has a file size and is newer than the current copy used by the process.  The line of code that causes the compiler error is "searchTime_ss >> searchTime;"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <locale>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::assign;
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace boost::algorithm;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost;

namespace boostfs = boost::filesystem;
namespace boostpt = boost::posix_time;

int CCon::checkFileStatus(std::string filename, std::string fileTime, bool dateTokenFound)
{
    int rval = 1;
    boostfs::path afile( filename );

    if( boostfs::file_size( afile ) <= 0 ) {
        rval = 0;
    } else
    if( dateTokenFound ) {

        std::time_t modtime = boostfs::last_write_time( afile );
        boostpt::ptime lastAccessTime = boostpt::from_time_t( modtime );
        boostpt::ptime searchTime(not_a_date_time);

        boostpt::time_input_facet *fin = new boostpt::time_input_facet( "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M" );
        std::stringstream searchTime_ss;  
        searchTime_ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), fin));

        searchTime_ss << fileTime;
        searchTime_ss >> searchTime;

        std::stringstream lastAccessTime_ss;
        lastAccessTime_ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), fin));
        lastAccessTime_ss << lastAccessTime;

        if( lastAccessTime < searchTime ) {
            rval = 0;
        } else {
            // log message that we are sending the file.
        }
    }
    return rval;
}
```

Below are the compiler errors I get from Visual Studio 2012:

```
W:\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost/date_time/time_facet.hpp(935) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::istreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> boost::date_time::time_input_facet<time_type,CharT>::get(InItrT &,InItrT &,std::ios_base &,time_type &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,bool) const' being compiled
with
[
_Elem=char,
_Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
time_type=boost::posix_time::ptime,
CharT=char,
InItrT=std::istreambuf_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>>,
_Alloc=std::allocator<char>
]
CCon.cpp(7348) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::date_time::time_input_facet<time_type,CharT>' being compiled
with
[
time_type=boost::posix_time::ptime,
CharT=char
]
W:\boost\boost_1_55_0\boost/date_time/format_date_parser.hpp(66): warning C4245: 'initializing' : conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned short', signed/unsigned mismatch
```

Here is the line from format_date_parser.hpp(66) that appears to be the culprit
int_type i = -1;

I have tried multiple combinations of including headers, but nothing helps.  I've searched Google for similar problems/solutions and find nothing that addresses this error which leads me to believe the problem is in my code, but I can't find it.  Very similar code running under CentOS and gcc works without issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That appears to be a warning... not an error.

Comment: I have the compiler set to treat warnings as errors. So far I have had no issues with Boost creating warnings until now.  Also, since the offending line of code is attempting to set an unsigned integer to -1, I would consider that an error, especially since that variable "i" is a return value.

Comment: With GCC that's a wise choice... with MSCL I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has been fixed because now with latest boost I can see a static_cast:

`int_type i = static_cast<int_type>(-1);`